# Codeigniter - Sending emails using different SMTP settings

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

I have a system that uses different emails for different parts of the system. I've got my config setup with a No-Reply email. However, if I try and send an email using different SMTP settings, it will try and use the Email config settings rather than the array settings I've specified.

These are the settings that are in my Email config file

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com'; 
$config['smtp_user'] = 'REMOVED';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'REMOVED';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; 
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n"; 
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '120';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
```

Below is the list of settings I have specified in the array (These are the settings that I want to send this particular email through Gmail rather than Office365)

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'REMOVED';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'REMOVED';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; 
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '120';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
```

Is there any way to send emails via different SMTP settings rather than the ones specified in the Email config file? I have tried to send this email via the Gmail settings but it always appears to try and send through the Email config settings.

SOLUTION:

```
 $config = array();
                        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
                        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                        $config['smtp_user'] = 'REMOVED';
                        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'REMOVED';
                        $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
                        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
                        $config['charset'] = 'utf8';
                        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
                        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard
                        $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
                        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '120';
                        $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';

                        $this->email->initialize($config);
```

Fixed my issue and now I am able to send an email through an Ad-Hoc Gmail account rather than the Office365 one.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your gmail config is being built as an array in the same controller you wish to use to send the email, correct? if so, aside from building the `$config[]` array, are you passing to the mail library upon initialization with `$this->email->initialize($config);` ? (this needs to be done before "building" the rest of the email IIRC)

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Essentially I have two sets of SMTP details. I have one set of SMTP details in the Email.php file. The other set I've got in a function in an array.

I don't want to send this email through the normal SMTP details in the Email.php file. Instead, I want to send them using the details in this array. However, when I try doing this, it will always try to send through the Email.php settings and not the Gmail settings specified in the array.

Comment: By default, the email class will automatically use what's on `config/Email.php` (your office365 config) but passing the gmail config with a new array in the controller and initializing the email class with `$this->email->initialize($config);` should override the other one

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Wow I don't believe it was that simple to do. I kept doing $this->load->library('email', $config) all the time. I'll update and edit my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the configuration in the `config/Email.php` (office365 in your case) file with a specific one (gmail, in your case) by building the `$config` array in the controller and then use it to initialize the email library with:

```
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

For this to work you must initialize the library using the overriding `$config` before actually doing anything else that requires the class, or the default settings will be used automatically